# Conditional extract and cat on two column from a DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've two columns `Name` and `Address` in a Pandas DataFrame and I need to extract a part from the address column (between `1/` and `2/`) and add that to the end of the name. If the length of `Name` is 20 don't use a space as separator and if the length is <20 add a space as separator. (I don't care about the address for now)

Original:

```
Name                 | Address                                    
Tundra Microsystemat | 1/ions Art ltd2/24267 Davis Street Rome, GA 30161
Desert Networks      | 1/Inc2/1482 Fairfield Road Kewaskum, WI 53040
Mount Yellowhive Sec | 1/urity2/564 Turkey Pen Road New York, NY 10016
```

Desired:

```
Name                             | Address                                    
Tundra Microsystemations Art ltd | 1/ions Art ltd2/24267 Davis Street Rome, GA 30161
Desert Networks Inc              | 1/Inc2/1482 Fairfield Road Kewaskum, WI 53040
Mount Yellowhive Security        | 1/urity2/564 Turkey Pen Road New York, NY 10016
```

My code (without checking the length)

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.cat(df['Address'].str.extract(r'1/(.*)2/'),sep=' ', na_rep = '').str.strip()
```

Also tried this:

```
def get_name_lenght(name):
    if len(name) == 20:
        df['Name'].str.cat(df['Address'].str.extract(r'1/(.*)2/'),sep='', na_rep = '').str.strip()
    else:
        df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.cat(df['Address'].str.extract(r'1/(.*)2/'),sep=' ', na_rep = '').str.strip()

df['Name'].apply(get_name_lenght)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with check condition by [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
a = df['Name'].str.cat(df['Address'].str.extract(r'1/(.*)2/'),sep='', na_rep = '').str.strip()
b = df['Name'].str.cat(df['Address'].str.extract(r'1/(.*)2/'),sep=' ', na_rep = '').str.strip()

df['Name'] = np.where(df['Name'].str.len() == 20, a, b)
```